# Update a react component only on button click with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Application**:

1. Search bar with two text input fields (input1, input2)
2. Three buttons: SearchX, SearchY, Clear results
3. Both the searches can take input1 and input2 as parameters to give two different results.
4. There's a result component which takes both the inputs, action and renders the search component depending on the action.

```
function TestComponent() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');
  const [action, setAction] = useState(null);

  const onInput1Change = evt => setInput1(evt.target.value);
  const onInput2Change = evt => setInput2(evt.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={input1} onChange={onInput1Change} />
      <input type="text" value={input2} onChange={onInput2Change} />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction('SearchX')}>
        SearchX
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction('SearchY')}>
        SearchY
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction('Clear results')}>
        Clear results
      </button>
      <ResultComponent input1={input1} input2={input2} action={action} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ResultComponent({ input1, input2, action }) {
  if (action === 'SearchX') {
    return <SearchX input1={input1} input2={input2} />;
  }

  if (action === 'SearchY') {
    return <SearchY input1={input1} input2={input2} />;
  }

  if (action === 'Clear results') {
    return null;
  }

  return null;
}

function SearchX({ input1, input2 }) {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch and process X-way to get the result. Using timeout to simulate that
    const id = window.setTimeout(() => setResult(`Search X result with inputs: ${input1}, ${input2}`), 3000);
    return () => window.clearInterval(id);
  }, [input1, input2]);

  return <div>{result}</div>;
}

function SearchY({ input1, input2 }) {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch and process Y-way to get the result. Using timeout to simulate that
    const id = window.setTimeout(() => setResult(`Search Y result with inputs: ${input1}, ${input2}`), 3000);
    return () => window.clearInterval(id);
  }, [input1, input2]);

  return <div>{result}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Problem**:

We want the search to initiate **only when a button is clicked**. With below code, after the first search result, as soon as you change your input, the result component expectedly re-renders thereby initiating search again without button click

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Enter "input1" in first text box
2. Enter "input2" in second text box
3. Hit on "SearchX"
4. After 3 seconds you should see something like "Search X result with inputs: input1, input2"
5. Change any of the input boxes. Need not press enter.
6. After 3 seconds, the result would change without button click

**Possible option**:

Planning to use React.memo hook to compare action prop before updating the result component. Action prop can only change on button clicks and hence can solve the problem.

**Question**:

1. Is there any other way (any other hooks etc.) to solve the problem?
2. Or is there any other process/design that I can follow to avoid memo ?

Comment: You need to reset your action after each result in search components changed but your ResultComponent will render null again until you press a button. Would having separate values (input1, input2) for each search component work?

Comment: Not really. Can have only one set of input1, input2.

Answer (score 1):

You could, upon input interaction, reset the action back to null. This will clear out the current result and not trigger a "search".

```
function TestComponent() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState('');
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState('');
  const [action, setAction] = useState(null);

  const onInput1Change = evt => {
    setInput1(evt.target.value);
    setAction(null);
  };
  const onInput2Change = evt => {
    setInput2(evt.target.value)
    setAction(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={input1} onChange={onInput1Change} />
      <input type="text" value={input2} onChange={onInput2Change} />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction('SearchX')}>
        SearchX
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction('SearchY')}>
        SearchY
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction(null)}>
        Clear results
      </button>
      <ResultComponent input1={input1} input2={input2} action={action} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT** Use html5 forms to save input and set action upon submit. When inputs are interacted with the inputs in state aren't updated until form is submitted.

```
function TestComponent() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const [action, setAction] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        id="searchX"
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setInput1(e.target.inputX.value);
          setAction("SearchX");
        }}
      />
      <form
        id="searchY"
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setInput2(e.target.inputY.value);
          setAction("SearchY");
        }}
      />

      <input id="inputX" form="searchX" type="text" />
      <input id="inputY" form="searchY" type="text" />

      <input form="searchX" type="submit" value="SearchX" />
      <input form="searchY" type="submit" value="SearchY" />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction(null)}>
        Clear results
      </button>

      <ResultComponent input1={input1} input2={input2} action={action} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit amazing-cori-97g7e]

Also, setting the "clear results" button action back to `null` saves a conditional check in `ResultComponent`, which simplifies to:

```
function ResultComponent({ input1, input2, action }) {
  if (action === 'SearchX') {
    return <SearchX input1={input1} input2={input2} />;
  }

  if (action === 'SearchY') {
    return <SearchY input1={input1} input2={input2} />;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: This would mean that the first result will clear off as soon as I start typing in input text field. This would be undesirable. The results should stay as it is unless a new result is requested upon.

Comment: @MohitK. Updated answer with another possible solution.

Comment: As I understand inputs should not be in different forms. So this solution is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @strdr4605 it's two forms with an input each that does reproduce the OP's desired behavior as I understand it to be, prefaced as being *one* possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use refs to inputs and only update state on button click.

```js
export default function TestComponent() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const [action, setAction] = useState(null);

  const input1Ref = useRef(null);
  const input2Ref = useRef(null);

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    if (input1Ref.current) {
      setInput1(input1Ref.current.value);
    }
    if (input2Ref.current) {
      setInput2(input2Ref.current.value);
    }
  };

  const onSearchXClick = () => {
    onButtonClick();
    setAction("SearchX");
  };

  const onSearchYClick = () => {
    onButtonClick();
    setAction("SearchX");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={input1Ref} type="text" />
      <input ref={input2Ref} type="text" />
      <button type="button" onClick={onSearchXClick}>
        SearchX
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={onSearchYClick}>
        SearchY
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setAction("Clear results")}>
        Clear results
      </button>
      <ResultComponent input1={input1} input2={input2} action={action} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit silly-maxwell-usrrj]

Comment: Haven't had much interaction with useRef. Let me do some hands on and see if it solves our problem. Thank you

Comment: onButtonClick we are setting two states (input1 and input2), but surprisingly none of them cause re-render. Instead re-render is triggered when action state is updated.
how is it possible that state changes don't cause re-render ?

Comment: When the input is typed I don't change the state, I change it only on button click

Comment: Correct, but when you press the button, onButtonClick sets two states input1 and input2. None of those trigger a re-render. Component re-renders only when last state (action) is set. This is probably because of state batching updates in react